# How to update my charts built with chart js by changing the range slider?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to update my chart using a range slider. A range slider typically here means a time slider, where in I can slide it and vary the time and simulatenously my chart also varies.
here is the code, I have got the slider but on moving , it does not affect the xaxis of my charts.
Any help is highly appreciated.
For now the xaxis is a range of number but in real my 24 hours time points will be there.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="form-group mt-3 mb-3">
        <label for="dataSet">Select Data</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="dataSet">
          <option id="opt1" value="1">All</option>
          <option id="opt2" value="2">Ambient</option>
          <option id="opt3" value="3">Booth</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="form-group mt-3 mb-3">
        <label for="dataOption">Select Options</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="dataOption">
          <option id="dt1" value="1">All</option>
          <option id="dt2" value="2">Temperature</option>
          <option id="dt3" value="3">Humidity</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <canvas id="mixedChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="time-range">
        <label>time</label>
        <input id="hour-slider"
               type="range" min="0" max="23"
        style="width: 800px;" value="1800" 
               </div>


$(document).ready(function () {
  var options = {
    type: "line",
    data: {
      labels: [10,20,30,40,50,60],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Ambient Temp",
          data: [4, 15, 16, 5, 30, 17],
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'
        },
        {
          label: "Ambient Humidity",
          data: [3, 10, 25, 8, 12, 4],
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
        },
        {
          label: "Booth Temp",
          data: [2, 19,26,8,12,28],
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)'
        },
        {
          label: "Booth Humidity",
          data: [1, 5,28,29,14,9],
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [
          {
            ticks: {
              reverse: false
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  };
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
  var chart = new Chart(ctx, options);
  
  function graphViews(){
    var dataVal = $('#dataSet').val();
    var optVal = $('#dataOption').val();
    
    if(dataVal == "1" && optVal == "1"){
      chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = false;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden = false;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = false;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = false;
      chart.update();
      chart.options.animation = true;
      chart.options.animation.duration = 1000;
      chart.options.animation.easing = 'linear';
      chart.options.animation.from = 1;
      chart.options.animation.to = 0;
    }
    else if(dataVal == "1" && optVal == "2"){
      chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = false;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden = true;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = false;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = true;
      chart.update();
    }
    else if(dataVal == "1" && optVal == "3"){
      chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = true;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden = false;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = true;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = false;
      chart.update();
    }
    else if(dataVal == "2" && optVal == "1"){
      chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = false;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden = false;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = true;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = true;
      chart.update();
    }
    else if(dataVal == "2" && optVal == "2"){
      chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = false;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden = true;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = true;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = true;
      chart.update();
    }
    else if(dataVal == "2" && optVal == "3"){
      chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = true;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden = false;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = true;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = true;
      chart.update();
    }
    else if(dataVal == "3" && optVal == "1"){
      chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = true;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden = true;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = false;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = false;
      chart.update();
    }
    else if(dataVal == "3" && optVal == "2"){
      chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = true;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden = true;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = false;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = true;
      chart.update();
    }
    else if(dataVal == "3" && optVal == "3"){
      chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = true;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden = true;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = true;
      chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = false;
      chart.update();
    }
  };
  
  $('#dataSet').on('change', function() {
    graphViews();
  });
  
  $('#dataOption').on('change', function() {
    graphViews();
  });
  
});
$(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
    onFinish: function (myChart) {
        // Called then action is done and mouse is released
        console.log(myChart.to);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue is: you never execute ionRangeSlider because out of dom ready.

Instead of myChart.to you need to use myChart.from.

For the x-axis, if you intend the labels the solution is:

```
$(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
    onFinish: function (myChart) {
        var newxLabels = chart.data.labels.map(function(e) {
            return  Math.round((+e * myChart.from) / 100);
        });
        chart.data.labels = newxLabels;
        chart.update();
    }
});
```

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        type: "line",
        data: {
            labels: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Ambient Temp",
                    data: [4, 15, 16, 5, 30, 17],
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'
                },
                {
                    label: "Ambient Humidity",
                    data: [3, 10, 25, 8, 12, 4],
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
                },
                {
                    label: "Booth Temp",
                    data: [2, 19, 26, 8, 12, 28],
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)'
                },
                {
                    label: "Booth Humidity",
                    data: [1, 5, 28, 29, 14, 9],
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [
                    {
                        ticks: {
                            reverse: false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    };
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, options);

    function graphViews() {
        var dataVal = $('#dataSet').val();
        var optVal = $('#dataOption').val();

        if (dataVal == "1" && optVal == "1") {
            chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = false;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden = false;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = false;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = false;
            chart.update();
            chart.options.animation = true;
            chart.options.animation.duration = 1000;
            chart.options.animation.easing = 'linear';
            chart.options.animation.from = 1;
            chart.options.animation.to = 0;
        }
        else if (dataVal == "1" && optVal == "2") {
            chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = false;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden = true;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = false;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = true;
            chart.update();
        }
        else if (dataVal == "1" && optVal == "3") {
            chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = true;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden = false;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = true;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = false;
            chart.update();
        }
        else if (dataVal == "2" && optVal == "1") {
            chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = false;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden = false;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = true;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = true;
            chart.update();
        }
        else if (dataVal == "2" && optVal == "2") {
            chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = false;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden = true;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = true;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = true;
            chart.update();
        }
        else if (dataVal == "2" && optVal == "3") {
            chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = true;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden = false;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = true;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = true;
            chart.update();
        }
        else if (dataVal == "3" && optVal == "1") {
            chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = true;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden = true;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = false;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = false;
            chart.update();
        }
        else if (dataVal == "3" && optVal == "2") {
            chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = true;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden = true;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = false;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = true;
            chart.update();
        }
        else if (dataVal == "3" && optVal == "3") {
            chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = true;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden = true;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = true;
            chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = false;
            chart.update();
        }
    };

    $('#dataSet').on('change', function () {
        graphViews();
    });

    $('#dataOption').on('change', function () {
        graphViews();
    });

    $(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
        onFinish: function (myChart) {
            var newxLabels = chart.data.labels.map(function(e) {
                return  Math.round((+e * myChart.from) / 100);
            });

            chart.data.labels = newxLabels;
            chart.update();
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2"></div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="form-group mt-3 mb-3">
                <label for="dataSet">Select Data</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="dataSet">
                    <option id="opt1" value="1">All</option>
                    <option id="opt2" value="2">Ambient</option>
                    <option id="opt3" value="3">Booth</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="form-group mt-3 mb-3">
                <label for="dataOption">Select Options</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="dataOption">
                    <option id="dt1" value="1">All</option>
                    <option id="dt2" value="2">Temperature</option>
                    <option id="dt3" value="3">Humidity</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2"></div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2"></div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <canvas id="mixedChart"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="time-range">
    <label>time</label>
    <input id="hour-slider"
           type="range" min="0" max="23"
           style="width: 800px;" value="1800" class="js-range-slider">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks, this is nicely working here. But when i use this in my codpen.io , it is not working. Do you know why?

Comment: did you include the libs, html, js correclty like in the snippet? If it works here there is no reason because it cannot work in jsfiddle, copen, browser.......

Comment: Hello, yes i tried that in my VS code editor, It is is working :) the labels are changing, yes. but the charts are not and while sliding it back , the labels of the chart are becoming all 0 , they are not like changing again..